# Unable to auto update Java 8

Tags: windows-10, java

after recently doing a fresh install of Win10 on my desktop PC, I installed the (at that time) most recent Java JDK for x64 and x86 including the corresponding JREs. Eversince I get the following error message just before the autoupdater completed downloading the current update:

```
Download failed:
from=http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/GetFile/1.8.0_66-b18/windows-i586/au.msi,
to=C:\Users\Me\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_66\au.msi
```

when updating manually by downloading the installer from the website, installing the new version and removing the old one.. that works, but when the next update comes out, the error will reappear.

Also, and I have to say that this is just a guess and I don't know for certain: The Java version in the error message always seems to be the same.

I tried deleting Java temporary files and certain AppData folders as some google searching suggested this solution, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Currently, the following Java Version is installed on my Win10 x64 system:

```
Oracle Java 8 Update 65
Oracle Java 8 Update 65 (x64 bit)
Orace Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 65
Orace Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 65 (x64 bit)
```

Comment: @Ramhound ..so? It's the x86 version trying to auto update. The x64 simply doesn't have an autoupdater and thus cannot produce even produce an error...

Comment: I suggest you read more carefully, though I admit that the formatting of the last paragraph is incorrectly displayed..
"I installed the (at that time) most recent Java JDK for x64 and x86 including the corresponding JREs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution to this problem was to remove the JRE that was installed with Oracle JDK and reinstall it using the Oracle JRE standalone installer.

This however was after 05.02.2016 so it may just have been fixed by oracle in accordance to what 0xF said.

Answer (score 1):

The au.msi is correctly downloaded but Windows 10 will prevent its execution because the package is not signed. Nothing is displayed on the screen (because I guess it is launched silently by the installation process), resulting in a timeout (as you can see in the jusched.log trace file)

So either wait for Oracle to sign au.msi, either launch the offline installer as explained above

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this error message on Win7 SP1 x64 for several weeks, since 2015-11-20 (when I made a screenshot of the message) until yesterday.

Today (2016-02-05) the installer finished successfully. I wasn't messing anything about Java, network settings nor temporary files.
Therefore my guess is that Oracle has made some fix, please retry now.

Comment: Is this a guess or an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when I had 32-bit and 64-bit Java installed in parallel. Uninstalling the 32-bit version solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "windows Offline" installation instead of "windows onLine" installation.
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
open the link above and select Offline installation.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to running installation files with administrator rights.  If you download the installer, right click and "run as administrator" you will have no issues.

Another option is to reduce the level of authority windows requires to run .exe files.